# Is there a Patch release schedule? Can I request my org be upgraded to the latest Patch?

Tags: apex, platform-bug, patch, api-version, platform-event

I recently discovered a [bug that makes it impossible to deploy subscriber triggers on Platform Events](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/178495/2995).

In my sandbox environment, the bug appears to be fixed. Yay! Unfortunately, that patch has not been rolled out to my production instance, preventing go-live. Is there a way to find out when patch releases are scheduled? Or to request an upgrade?

Comment: May be useful - [How can I tell what is changing in Salesforce as they patch each pod?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/80546/102), though it is more after the fact than telling you when it is going to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you find the issue in the known issue list then it gives you some details about what pods it's been deployed to thus far.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index

I remember back in the day SF released patches on Wednesdays. I'm not sure if that's still the case but if you're right that it's fixed in a sandbox a production patch might not be far along, unless they determine it's a release issue and then you're stuck till next release.

For what it's worth I googled all over the place to find the known issue for this one but I couldn't find it. Did you log a case with Salesforce? Sometimes the rep can find a internal timeline that's not public.

Comment: Sandbox was patched more than seven days ago, I believe. I'm not sure they did ever post a Known Issue. :(

Comment: Do you have a bug number or issue number? I know some T3 people who know some people.

Comment: You can see it in the comments on the linked post. Apparently it was fixed in Patch 10.0 though...hmm. Maybe they reverted the fix or something...

Comment: Strange, the patch says 10.0 but on the side it says patch 12.4 or 12.5 which if you go to that url https://success.salesforce.com/issues_releases_view?release=208012400 it says not deployed...

Comment: I think you meant https://success.salesforce.com/issues_releases_view?release=208012004

Comment: Ha good catch, I checked with my friend best advice is reopen the support case or log a new one that's it's not fixed at least you'll find out the actual known issue and can follow it there.